# JSDoc not recognizing exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc3

I'm making a node.js project, and work in Webstorm, where functions are usually highlighted in yellow. However in the following scenario,  `fnA`  is not recognized as a function in file b.

```
//file a.js
module.exports = fnA;

/**
 * Converts val to someOtherVal
 * @param val
 * @return someOtherVal
 */

function fnA( val ){
   //Do something with val....
   return someOtherVal
}
```

---

```
//file b.js

var fnA = requires('./a.js');

function fnB() {
  var c = fnA(3); //<- not recognized as a function
}
```

However if I wrap the function in a namespace, it works properly:

```
 //a.js
 module.exports = fnA;

/**
 * Converts val to someOtherVal
 * @param val
 * @memberof core
 */

function fnA( val ){
   //Do something with val....
   return someOtherVal
}
__________________________________________________
//b.js
/**
 * @namespace
 */
var core = {
   fnA : requires('./a.js')
}


function b() {
  var c = core.fnA(3); //Recognized as a function
}
```

I would like to avoid wrapping the function in a namespace - what is the proper way to jsdoc the function in the first example?

Comment: The issue is that you're assigning it to `module.exports`, which webstorm recognizes as an object (which it is, by default.) Try doing something like `module.exports.fnA = fnA` and importing it with `require('./a.js').fnA`.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

same issue in JSDoc 3.6.6 (functions defined with an export not recognized)

Workaround:
Define functions without export and export an object.

```
//file.js
const function1 = () => {
  ...
}
const function2 = () => {
  ...
}

export {
  function1,
  function2
}
```